# How do I know when OneDrive background download has completed?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, onedrive

The (small) sample code from Microsoft for background downloads with Windows Runtime apps is:

```
try
{
    LiveDownloadOperation operation = await connectClient.CreateBackgroundDownloadAsync(filePath);
    var result = await operation.StartAsync();
    // Handle result.
}
catch
{
    // Handle errors.
}
```

I'm using the variant of CreateBackgroundDownloadAsync where you can specify a StorageFile as the second parameter, causing the downloaded file to be stored as that StorageFile.

How do I know when the download has completed? result doesn't seem to have any properties I can check, nor does there seem to be any event that gets fired.

The documentation is sorely lacking :-(.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was being rather forgetful about the whole async/await piece.

When

```
var result = await operation.StartAsync();
```

actually puts a value into result, the download has finished. Similarly when reconnecting to downloads that were in-progress when the app was terminated - the await calls will finish when the downloads finish.

I still think the Live SDK documentation is very poor compared with the rest of the MSDN documentation and Microsoft need to put some work into it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments on the documentation. We're working on a whole new process for our documentation for OneDrive APIs. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

From perusing the API docs, it *appears* you do two things:

1. First, add a handler to the [`BackgroundDownloadCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.live.liveconnectclient.backgrounddownloadcompleted.aspx) event. This will be raised if the download completes while your app is still active
2. When your app is activated, call [`GetCurrentBackgroundDownloadsAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.livconnectclient.getcurrentbackgrounddownloadsasync.aspx) to re-connect to anything that was in-progress while your app was terminated via the [`AttachAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659762.aspx) method.